# Change Google Maps API key at run time in android

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I have developed an Android app for two different clients.
I don't want my clients to use my API key. So it is required to set their individual keys. But I can't find a way to change the API key set in google_maps_api.xml file.

Any idea?

Comment: API keys are generated for a given package name, and the app needs to be signed with a given certificate. Changing only the API key will never work.